# i have to write a program in python to check that 3 ,11 are prime numbers whereas 9 is not

Tags: python, list, data-structures, iteration, range

I have written this code, for that but its returning 9 as a prime number too.
when i am putting 9 as the input i am getting below output.
*enter a number:9
it is a prime number
not a prime number*

```
num = int(input("enter a number:"))

for i in range(2,num):
    if num % i == 0:
        print("not a prime number")
    else:
        print("it is a prime number")
```

but this is showing 9 is a prime number too

Comment: It's only a prime number if the loop _makes it all the way through_ without finding a divisor.

Comment: See [How much research?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  This is a common mistake in search code in any language, and particularly prime detectors.  Finding a correct prime-number program is a trivial on-line search.  We expect you to include that research in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can just `break` the loop inside if condition, and pull the else part out of the loop, it'll behave the way you are looking for.

Inside the loop, if the number is divisible, it means it's not a prime, and loop immediately breaks, but if it makes all the way to `else` part of for loop, it means that the number is prime; this else part will be executed *only if the loop was not manually broken*.

```py
num = int(input("enter a number:"))

for i in range(2,num):
    if num % i == 0:
        print("not a prime number")
        break
else:
    print("it is a prime number")
```

**PS**: You don't even need to check upto `n`, you can just check upto √n, more information at [Wikipedia Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)